# Prevent ^C from being displayed on Ctrl+C in Go

Tags: go

I'd like to prevent "^C" from being outputted to the terminal when Ctrl+C is pressed.

I'm capturing the interrupt command like this:

```
c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGTERM)
go func() {
    <-c
    // exit code here
}()
```

... however, when I press Ctrl+C, "^C" is outputted into the terminal. This isn't ideal.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think that may be either the terminal or the shell (in either case, not your program), so unless you can instruct whichever is outputting the `^C` not to do that (via some IPC mechanism?) I'm not sure that you can do anything about it.

Comment: Yeah I thought that might be the answer.

Comment: You could use the `kill` command to send the signal to the process, thereby curcumventing the shell, if the `^C` does NOT show then, you can be relatively certain that it's the shell or terminal printing this.

Comment: Confirmed: https://superuser.com/questions/147013/how-to-disable-c-from-being-echoed-on-linux-on-ctrl-c

Comment: When you input `^C` at the terminal, it generates `SIGINT`, not `SIGTERM`.

Answer (score 9):

If you print something afterwards, you can do

```
fmt.Print("\r")
log.Println("Shutting down")
```

`\r` is a carriage return character; it tells your terminal emulator to move the cursor at the start of the line. This way you can overwrite the `^C` on the terminal.

Comment: Super awesome - I bet Python does that too.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the terminal into raw mode, you'll get the keystrokes directly and the tty won't interpret them (and display ^C).

I'm not sure of the best way to set raw mode in Go, but golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal's RawMode() does it. You would then have to enable INT and TERM handling otherwise you'll receive a ^C as input, instead having it be processed as an interruption.

An explanation of raw mode is here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/what-s-the-difference-between-a-raw-and-a-cooked-device-driver

A similar answer is here: https://superuser.com/questions/147013/how-to-disable-c-from-being-echoed-on-linux-on-ctrl-c